# How do I get a trigger to run for every editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build a method for creating a shared contact group.   The API's are there so that if an editor clicks snyc contacts it can snyc with "Their" own contacts.   But I am not sure how to make that work as an automated trigger.   I am OK with each editor authorizing, but can each one have their own timed trigger?

UPDATE: This issue is moot as each trigger is already set to the users.

Comment: Do you intend to build a standalone app or will you embed it in some document?

Comment: It is a spreadsheet.   Right now every user needs to set up their own trigger.  Which is not such a bad thing as it is like a form of authorization.

Comment: you could write a script callable from menu to create the trigger so that each user can make it work in his name easily.

Comment: Serge, that is how I have it working now.   (kind-of I just ran into a permission issue)

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand... what else do you want to do exactly and what issue do you have ?

Comment: My hope was for user A to be able to set up a trigger for user B,C & D.

Comment: I probably should mark this as solved, since it does appear to work if they end-user clicks accept.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Apps Script to have a script that allows a user to create triggers for other users directly.

As stated, it is possible to create a menu item or UI control that will allow users of a script/add-on to create triggers for themselves. The [Form Notifications add-on](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-form-notifications-addon) has an example of this, where a sidebar control creates or removes form submit triggers for the user of the add-on.